# How to compress this code into one block

Tags: javascript, html

I want to compress all this code into a single block instead of 5. It works perfect, but it is very bloated. Any other tips for improving this code would be greatly appreciated.

JS:

```
function vanish1() {
    var el = document.getElementById('priceCheck1');
    if (el.style.display == "block") {
        el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        el.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function vanish2() {
    var el = document.getElementById('priceCheck2');
    if (el.style.display == "block") {
        el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        el.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function vanish3() {
    var el = document.getElementById('priceCheck3');
    if (el.style.display == "block") {
        el.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        el.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="priceCheck1">
test1
    </div>
    <div id="priceCheck2">   
test2
    </div>    
    <div id="priceCheck3">
test3
    </div>
```

Comment: Forgot to add the CSS.
They are all display: none;

Comment: How are you invoking the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
function vanish(elementName) {
    var el = document.getElementById(elementName);
    if (el.style.display == "block") el.style.display = "none";
    else el.style.display = "block";
}
```

Function call:

```
vanish('priceCheck1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can add a class name for the HTML.
then you can get each HTML by classname..

Answer (score 0):

Even smaller...

```
function vanish(style) {
    style.display == "block" ? style.display = "none" : style.display = "block";
}

vanish(document.getElementById("priceCheck1").style);
```

or

```
function vanish(element) {
    element.style.display == "block" ? element.style.display = "none" : element.style.display = "block";
}

vanish(document.getElementById("priceCheck1"));
```

Comment: Yes, but do keep the document.getElementById in the function though. That is just a bit nicer I would say